# Wordpress functions to create basic functionalities to admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, menu, admin

I'm writing a plugin for wordpress, but interface was terrible so I want to change it to look like other plugins in a standard way like this

[image]

but is there some set of defined functions? Or do I have to write everything by myself in html? I don't want to use other plugins for panel building since I'm writing plugin myself.

Comment: I think you are looking for Hooks and Actions. Your question is too general in my opinion. Try going through the WordPress Codex first: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin and if you still have trouble, ask a more specific question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking, you need to use `WP_List_Table`: standard admin "style",bulk-actions.. what you looking ( I've done a few plugins with this class ).  See [WP_List_Table – a step by step guide](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) .

*Advice* You can download plugin-example [Custom List Table Example](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/) for starting and modify it.